# Updated gitignore but files still being tracked

Tags: git, gitignore

I just updated my `.gitignore` so I ignore certain files, but when I sync my changes they are still there on github.

Please help me. I have tried many things.

Edit: I looked at those but I don't want to do those because it changes the repo. I want it the gitignore to only work for me

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore

Comment: could you post your gitignore file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to untrack a specific file you can use this command:

```
git rm --cached filename
```

If you want to untrack a lot of new files that you added to your gitignore you can do this:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to delete ignored files from the repo with `git rm` if it is already there.